# Recommendations for populating formatted content pages from the database

Tags: html, laravel

I'm working on my first laravel project- a family tree website. Everything's going great with the normal models/controllers/views, but I've gotten to a special case that I'm not sure how to approach. I have about a dozen auxiliary stories that go along with specific people or families- this is extra stuff that most records don't have.

In my previous incarnation of this site, I had a stories table with a headline, source for the material, and a slug, I made an html page for each story, and then I'd link to that page using the slug value.

In Laravel this seems like a really clunky way to go about it (especially as I add more stories), because it's messy to have to make a new route/controller/view for each one.

So I've made a general StoryController and view in hopes of reusing that to display the contents of any story. I've added a 'text' column into my stories table for those contents, and I've copied the HTML (with the problematic characters escaped).  But of course when I display this story text on the view, I see all the markup tags displayed themselves (instead of helping to render the actual text in paragraphs, etc).

So two questions: is there a way to treat the field as html itself (instead of a string)?  And is my approach off-base and I should do this a different way?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update**: thanks to The Happy Mamba, it works if I call to another function for html_entity_decode and echo out the results, but weirdly it DOESN'T work if I 'return' the results (or do it in the same function).  It didn't render the tags until I did it like so (in StoryController):

```
public function convert($string)
{
    echo (html_entity_decode($string));
}

public function show($id)
{
    $story = Story::find($id);
    $content = StoryController::convert($story->text);

    return view ('story/show',  compact('story', 'content'));
}
```

The snag there is that because it's using echo, that field is displayed first no matter what.... so if I can't get around that I'll need to conversion in and out of the database as suggested (still need to get the Connection string working)- but this is a great step forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pulling it out of the database and then sending the text to [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Here's some code to test it.  Examples are in postgresql but should work the same with PDO/laravel specific functions:

```
<?php

$conn = pg_connect('db connection string here');

$text = pg_escape_literal( $conn, htmlentities( '<html><head></head><body><em>test</em></body></html>' ) );

pg_query( $conn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE test' );
pg_query( $conn, "INSERT INTO test VALUES ( {$text} )" );

$result = pg_query( $conn, 'SELECT * FROM test' );

$row = pg_fetch_row( $result );
pg_close( $conn );

$string = $row[0];

echo html_entity_decode($string);

?>
```

Result:

bolded "test" in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I tried that just now, and that's the right idea but maybe backwards?  What happens is my "<p>stuff here</p>" becomes "&lt;p&gt;stuff here&lt;p&gt;"

Comment: On that same page you referenced, I see ENT_HTML5, which sounds like it would do the trick- when I try that I get 'call to undefined function', but maybe I just need to include something...looking...

Comment: Ok try htmlspecialchars on putting into db and htmlspecialchars_decode on pulling it out.  htmlentities has the same _decode function.  I usually prefer not storing html in the database for a variety of reasons, but trying to answer the question.  :)

Comment: Thank you!  Yes I feel weird about storing html in the database too- it just seems *wrong*.  I'm not familiar with other options that I can pass to a view in laravel, but I'm ALL EARS  :)

I just tried htmlspecialchars_decode to display it, and it looks like that happens already by default (the &lt; in the database is displayed as <), the same with and without using that function.  I'm intrigued by ENT_HTML5 on that page... exploring that trail for now...

Comment: It'll probably be fine with what you are doing.  If editing the html becomes more complicated or burdensome, you can look at other options (storing them in files, using partials, etc)

Comment: Unfortunately no dice with ENT_HTML5- it's more of the same with decoding and encoding, it doesn't make it look less like a string.  Stuck again, will sleep on it

Comment: Thank you for giving more info- I'm battling with the nuts and bolts of connecting to the database explicitly (with Laravel everything's sort of abstracted away)- and haven't been able to successfully get there to see your suggestion in action.  Stepping away to clear my head and hopefully have insight when I come back fresh.  Either that or do something horrendous like just have a different database field for each paragraph and be done with it (kidding.... but tempted :p)

Comment: So it was the weirdest thing in the world: I'll update my description above with the code, but it works when I pass the text to a function that simply does this:         echo (html_entity_decode($string));

Weirdly it DOES NOT work if I have the same function return (html_entity_decode($string)); or use it in my regular show function (in both of those cases it still displays the tags).  I'm so glad it's working, and so surprised- I guess I don't really understand echo. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things, the solution I like best is to make a partial for each story, and then dynamically include the correct one based on the story.slug.  (This way I still need only one story route/show function/view, and I can update the content much more easily than if I'm cramming html into the database)